# ".then is not a function" from a very simple inquirer program

Tags: node.js, inquirer

the very simple example below (pretty much copied off the npm inquirer front page) is giving the ".then is not a function" error. However I can't figure out what the issue is.

```
var inquirer = require('inquirer');

inquirer.prompt([
        {
            name: 'my_name',
            type: 'input',
            message: 'What is your name: '
        }]).then(answers => {
                    console.log("Your name is:"+answers.my_name)            
                    });
```

The error message looks like this:

```
? What is your name:

/home/peter/Documents/nodejs.d/vscode_examples_workspace/security/inq.js:8
        }]).then(answers => {
            ^

TypeError: inquirer.prompt(...).then is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/peter/Documents/nodejs.d/vscode_examples_workspace/security/inq.js:8:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:516:3)
```

But the following example works OK. So the basic node.js environment (nodejs --version = v9.11.2) is OK.

```
var inquirer = require('inquirer');

let q = [
    {
        name: 'my_name',
        type: 'input',
        message: 'What is your name: '
    }];

inquirer.prompt (q, function (answers){
    console.log("Your name is: "+answers.my_name);
});

// Output
$ nodejs inq.js
? What is your name:  Peter
Your name is: Peter
```

Comment: Anthony, how do I find out? If I assign a variable to the result the program crashes out before a value is returned. Same if I add a .catch() statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because you have an old version of inquirer (0.12.0 or older) which does not support promises (promises were added in version 1.0.0).

Your snippet works fine with version 6.0.0 and 1.0.0 but fails with the exact same error message in version 0.12.0.

Check packages.json for your version and update it:

```
"dependencies": {
  "inquirer": "^6.0.0"
}
```

Then do

```
npm install
```

Comment: Tools like [NCU](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) can help check if your dependencies are out of date.

Comment: Yes. This looks to be the issue. Thank you. 
sudo npm list inquirer -g
/usr/lib
├── inquirer@6.0.0
└─┬ quotr@0.7.6
  └─┬ vorpal@1.12.0
    └── inquirer@0.11.0

Comment: Glad to help, if this resolves your issue be sure to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Yes resolved, while I had the correct version of inquirer, I also had an old version installed via vorpal. Not quite sure why it was electing to use the old version rather than the new, but making the dependencies clear in package.json solved the problem.